# Home/End keys in zsh don't work with putty

Tags: terminal, keyboard, zsh, terminal-emulator, terminfo

I'm running zsh as the default shell on a Ubuntu box, and everything works fine using gnome-terminal (which as far as I know emulates xterm). When I login from a windows box via ssh and putty (which also emulates xterm) suddendly the home/end keys no longer work.

I've been able to solve that adding these lines to my zshrc file...

```
bindkey '\e[1~' beginning-of-line
bindkey '\e[4~' end-of-line
```

...but I'm still wondering what's wrong here. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for the above bindings.  Working now for me in SecurtCRT

Comment: Thanks for the command. For me this setting worked: `bindkey '^[OH' beginning-of-line` and `bindkey '^[OF' end-of-line`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I found it's a combination:

**One**

The ZSH developers do not think that ZSH should define the actions of the <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, ... keys.

Debian and Ubuntu fix this by defining the normal actions the average user would expect in the global `/etc/zsh/zshrc` file. Following the relevant code (it is the same on Debian and Ubuntu):

```
if [[ "$TERM" != emacs ]]; then
[[ -z "$terminfo[kdch1]" ]] || bindkey -M emacs "$terminfo[kdch1]" delete-char
[[ -z "$terminfo[khome]" ]] || bindkey -M emacs "$terminfo[khome]" beginning-of-line
[[ -z "$terminfo[kend]" ]] || bindkey -M emacs "$terminfo[kend]" end-of-line
[[ -z "$terminfo[kich1]" ]] || bindkey -M emacs "$terminfo[kich1]" overwrite-mode
[[ -z "$terminfo[kdch1]" ]] || bindkey -M vicmd "$terminfo[kdch1]" vi-delete-char
[[ -z "$terminfo[khome]" ]] || bindkey -M vicmd "$terminfo[khome]" vi-beginning-of-line
[[ -z "$terminfo[kend]" ]] || bindkey -M vicmd "$terminfo[kend]" vi-end-of-line
[[ -z "$terminfo[kich1]" ]] || bindkey -M vicmd "$terminfo[kich1]" overwrite-mode

[[ -z "$terminfo[cuu1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[cuu1]" vi-up-line-or-history
[[ -z "$terminfo[cuf1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[cuf1]" vi-forward-char
[[ -z "$terminfo[kcuu1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[kcuu1]" vi-up-line-or-history
[[ -z "$terminfo[kcud1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[kcud1]" vi-down-line-or-history
[[ -z "$terminfo[kcuf1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[kcuf1]" vi-forward-char
[[ -z "$terminfo[kcub1]" ]] || bindkey -M viins "$terminfo[kcub1]" vi-backward-char

# ncurses fogyatekos
[[ "$terminfo[kcuu1]" == "^[O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcuu1]/O/[}" vi-up-line-or-history
[[ "$terminfo[kcud1]" == "^[O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcud1]/O/[}" vi-down-line-or-history
[[ "$terminfo[kcuf1]" == "^[O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcuf1]/O/[}" vi-forward-char
[[ "$terminfo[kcub1]" == "^[O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcub1]/O/[}" vi-backward-char
[[ "$terminfo[khome]" == "^[O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[khome]/O/[}" beginning-of-line
[[ "$terminfo[kend]" == "^[O"* ]] && bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kend]/O/[}" end-of-line
[[ "$terminfo[khome]" == "^[O"* ]] && bindkey -M emacs "${terminfo[khome]/O/[}" beginning-of-line
[[ "$terminfo[kend]" == "^[O"* ]] && bindkey -M emacs "${terminfo[kend]/O/[}" end-of-line
fi
```

So, if you are connecting to a Debian or Ubuntu box, you don't have to do anything. Everything should work automagically (if not, see below).

But... if you are connecting to another box (e.g. FreeBSD), there might be no user friendly default `zshrc`. The solution is of course to add the lines from the Debian/Ubuntu `zshrc` to your own `.zshrc`.

**Two**

Putty sends `xterm` as terminal type to the remote host. But messes up somewhere and doesn't send the correct control codes for <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, ... that one would expect from an `xterm`. Or an `xterm` terminal isn't expected to send those or whatever... (<kbd>Del</kbd> key does work in `xterm` however, if you configure it in ZSH). Also notice that your Numpad-keys act funny in Vim for example with `xterm` terminal.

The solution is to configure Putty to send another terminal type. I've tried `xterm-color` and `linux`. `xterm-color` fixed the <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> problem, but the Numpad was still funny. Setting it to `linux` fixed both problems.

You can set terminal type in Putty under Connection -> Data. Do not be tempted to set your terminal type in your `.zshrc` with `export TERM=linux`, that is just wrong. The terminal type should be specified by your terminal app. So that if, for example, you connect from a Mac box with a Mac SSH client it can set it's own terminal type.

Notice that TERM specifies your terminal type and has nothing to do with the host you are connecting to. I can set my terminal type to `linux` in Putty and connect to FreeBSD servers without problems.

So, fix both these things and you should be fine :)

Comment: Another waay to fix the funny keypad behaviour: Open the session settins, go to `Terminal -> Features` and check the box labelled `Disable application keypad mode`. See here: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-appkeypad

Comment: I had to add ``vi-beginning-of-line`` and ``vi-end-of-line`` bindings to viins mode aswell to completely fix my problem with zsh + putty. Now it works though.

Comment: I didn't have success with the .zshrc code that @hopla pasted. So I had to use the solution on the following zsh wiki page [http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys) in the section about reading from $terminfo[] plus hopla's solution about setting the terminal type to "linux". The ZSH wiki page says to do basically the same but without the "-M ..." options passed to bindkey. This only works in the "vi" bindkey mode for me though.

Comment: @exhuma fix worked for me. I was having trouble driving emacs on a CentOS5 box from Windows via PuTTy -> zsh -> tmux -> emacs

Comment: The terminal type for PuTTY has been `putty` in Dickey terminfo since 2001.  https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty

Answer (score 21):

On the PuTTY configuration dialog, go to Connection -> Data and type **linux** into the Terminal-type string before connecting.

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: This works for me but additionally, I must launch Midnight Commander using `mc -x` if I want to use the mouse in it.

Comment: There is no Connection --> Data section in PuTTY 0.73 64-bit for me in Win10, just Connection --> SSH, and I cannot find "Terminal-type" option anywhere.  Perhaps this answer is outdated?

Comment: @Eric nope, Connection --> Data is still in place for me in PuTTY 0.74 64-bit in Win10.

Answer (score 9):

It's now been nearly 11 years since this question was first posted.  At the time, some distros did ship with a `putty` terminfo entry, but it was mediocre at best.  In the years since, the situation has improved, and the hacks that were necessary for over a decade are no longer required.  PuTTY still defaults to setting `TERM` to `xterm` for compatibility, but if you're connecting to modern, up-to-date systems, you'll likely have luck overriding this and setting it to `putty-256color`:

1. Ensure the host has a terminfo entry for `putty-256color`: `toe -a | grep -F putty`
2. Undo any hacks you may have enabled to get PuTTY working properly with zsh or other programs.
3. Ensure PuTTY is up-to-date.  It won't notify you when updates are available, and if it's out-of-date, you're likely going to run into a lot of the same issues.  You may want to keep it up-to-date automatically with something like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).
4. In PuTTY's configuration dialog, go to Connection -> Data and set "Terminal-type string" to `putty-256color`.
5. While you're at it, on the same configuration screen, add a new environment variable to enable 24-bit color.  This variable isn't standardized, but it's sent by a number of other mainstream terminal emulators (e.g., iTerm2), and many programs understand it.

   1. Variable: `COLORTERM`
   2. Value: `truecolor`
6. As of writing, I haven't found a distro that accepts the COLORTERM variable over SSH by default.  You'll need to edit your OpenSSH configuration on the host to allow it.  For example, on Debian-like distros, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add `COLORTERM` to the `AcceptEnv` line.
7. Everything should now "just work".  If it doesn't:

   1. Ensure you've reconnected after making the change, or at least run `exec zsh` after changing `TERM`.  zsh won't react to changes in `TERM` while it's running.
   2. Ensure that `TERM` is actually set to what you intended: `echo $TERM`
   3. Are you on the latest version of your distro?  If you're on a long-term support lifecycle build, for example, even if your version is technically still supported, it may not have up-to-date terminfo entries.
   4. Are you using `screen` or `tmux`?  That's another whole can of worms.  Test without those first to narrow down where the issue is occurring.  Within tmux, try setting `TERM=tmux-256color`.  Within screen, try `TERM=screen-256color`.
   5. Are you on the latest version of PuTTY?
   6. Do you have RC-files that are implementing keybindings or other hacks?  Try using default RC-files.
   7. Did you already change various PuTTY settings to attempt to fix the issue before attempting the terminfo fix?  You'll probably need to reset those settings.

Comment: This worked for me on Gentoo - and Gentoo accepted COLORTERM without changes. Gentoo also has a screen terminfo for putty-256color so I'd expect screen to work as well.

Comment: I do not have Connection --> Data in PuTTY 0.73

Answer (score 7):

This is working for me

```
bindkey -v

bindkey '\eOH'  beginning-of-line
bindkey '\eOF'  end-of-line
```

Comment: That messed mine up (sort of). Now instead of a tilde, it's capitalizing and lowercasing my letters.

Comment: For me, bindkey -v was sufficient.

Comment: after putting that in my .zshrc: <c-p> and <c-n> doesn't work anymore and just prints out ^P^N - But using '\e[1~' and '\e[4~' works

Answer (score 6):

the appropriate answer that should be portable across *all* distros (not necessarly all versions of zsh though, ymmv here) is to use the zkbd helper utility from zkbd.

> Keyboard Definition
> The  large  number  of  possible  combinations  of keyboards, workstations, terminals, emulators, and window systems makes it impossible for zsh to have built-in key bindings for every situation.  The zkbd utility, found in Functions/Misc, can help you quickly create key bindings for your configuration.

> Run zkbd either as an autoloaded function, or as a shell script:

```
zsh -f ~/zsh-4.3.17/Functions/Misc/zkbd
```

> When you run zkbd, it first asks you to enter your terminal type; if the default it offers is correct, just press return.  It then asks you to press a number of different keys to determine characteristics of your keyboard and terminal; zkbd  warns  you
> if it finds anything out of the ordinary, such as a Delete key that sends neither ^H nor ^?.

> The  keystrokes  read  by zkbd are recorded as a definition for an associative array named key, written to a file in the subdirectory .zkbd within either your HOME or ZDOTDIR directory.  The name of the file is composed from the TERM, VENDOR and OSTYPE
> parameters, joined by hyphens.

> You may read this file into your .zshrc or another startup file with the `source` or `.` commands, then reference the key parameter in bindkey commands, like this:

```
          source ${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zkbd/$TERM-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE
          [[ -n ${key[Left]} ]] && bindkey "${key[Left]}" backward-char
          [[ -n ${key[Right]} ]] && bindkey "${key[Right]}" forward-char
          # etc.
```

> Note that in order for `autoload zkbd` to work, the `zkbd` file must be in one of the directories named in your fpath array (see zshparam(1)).  This should already be the case  if  you  have  a  standard  zsh  installation;  if  it  is  not,  copy  Functions/Misc/zkbd to an appropriate directory.

see `man -P "less -p 'keyboard definition'" zshcontrib`, or search the meta-manpage `zshall`

Answer (score 3):

It seems a putty thing. Gnome-terminal sends the codes `^[OH` and `^[OF` for Home and End respectively, while putty sends `^[[1~` and `^[[4~`. There's an option in putty to change the Home/End keys from *standard* mode to *rxvt* mode, and that seems to fix the Home key, but not the End key (which now sends `^[Ow`). Guess it's time to file a bug report somewhere... :-)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Adding these lines to ~/.zshrc

```
bindkey "\e[1;5D" backward-word
bindkey "\e[1;5C" forward-word

# ctrl-bs and ctrl-del
bindkey "\e[3;5~" kill-word
bindkey "\C-_"    backward-kill-word

# del, home and end
bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char
bindkey "\e[H"  beginning-of-line
bindkey "\e[F"  end-of-line

# alt-bs
bindkey "\e\d"  undo
```

Answer (score 0):

These bindings simply don't appear to be part of the default bindings set in emacs mode.

executing "where-is beginning-of-line" on my default zsh installation after running "bindkey -e" shows it is only bound to ^a. Perhaps you should ask the zsh developers why :-)

Comment: The default ubuntu install binds them in a global zshrc file, but as far as I can see the bindings don't work for putty.